# Restore MySQL database only from: ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1

Tags: mysql, system, restore, tablespace

I accidentally removed a database from my system along with all web data by using Plesk control panel. We don't have any sql backups there. What I have at this moment is: ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 (**I don't have any *.frm files as well**).
Is there any way how to restore the database?
I tried to recover the files with **scalpel** utility, but it's not possible to restore everything.

Comment: [This might help](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57120/recover-mysql-database-from-data-folder-without-ibdata1-from-ibd-files). However, you will have to somehow restore the table definition - do you have any code or anything that can help you create empty tables? Without that, it would appear you are royally f..

Comment: It was Magento. I asked a web developer and he has recently updated site, but without any databases. What exactly I need to take care about?

Comment: `.frm` files contain table definition. You need them. Since you lost that, you should try to reconstruct the database without data and then follow the link I posted. It could be tricky and if this site earns you money, consider hiring an expert to restore the db with data.